# TcxGridDBBandedTableView cell selection issues with Devexpress VCL 13.1.2

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I am using `Devexpress VCL 13.1.2`. I have a table view like following

```
myView : TcxGridDBBandedTableView
```

When I click on the first cell (`TcxGridDBBandedColumn`) of this table view (`TcxGridDBBandedTableView`), it gets selected (background becomes blue). When I press Right Arrow key now, next columns get selected and the previous column is un-selected. It is working well.

But when I hit TAB, next column remain un-selected. I have tried each and every property of TcxGridDBBandedTableView, but with no success!!

Has anybody experienced similar problem with `TcxGridDBBandedTableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the tableview property `optionsbehavior.FocusCellonTab = True`

Comment: When I set it to true, it only highlights the border. It does not change the full background of the cell to blue unlike when I use RIGHT ARROW.

Comment: And what's the value of the 'FocusCellOnCycle' property?

Comment: There is a difference between 'focus' and 'selection'. Because you clicked the first cell, it has got 'focus' and is 'selected'.  By moving to the next cell with keyboard (right arrow e.g.), the next item got 'focus', but therefore is not automatically selected.  I don't think there's a property to get this behavior, you have to do this programatically.

Comment: I tried around a bit, there is a property to mimic this behaviour: set optionsbehavior.alwaysshoweditor to true.

Comment: So, is it not possible? In my Delphi 7 application, I am using older version of Devexpress which is working fine and I have to copy same functionality in Devex 13.1.

Comment: I tried AlwaysShowEditor, but it is something different. It only selects the content in the cell, not the entire cell.